# Data Comparison between Two Tables

Tags: sql

I have what should be simple (maybe) and I am just struggling with it.

Here is the scenario:
TABLE 1 contains all the data
TABLE 2 contains only a subset

I need a query that will look at table 1 and give a list of items that are not in table 2.  Below is what I have but I know its not performing as such.

```
SELECT c.[DOC_ID], d.[DOCID]
FROM [dbo].[Custom_SUAM_Docuware] d 
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Custom_SUAM_Content] c ON (c.[DOC_ID] = d.[DOCID])
WHERE c.[DOC_ID] IS NULL
    OR d.[DOCID] IS NULL
```

Comment: Your problem is your `OR` statement. Because of it I feel that you need to add a bit more of explanation to your question, like table 1 here being `Custom_SUAM_Docuware` it means you want to list everything on it which `DOC_ID` and when that is not the case the ones that are not on table 2?

Comment: Just removing this `c.[DOC_ID] IS NULL  OR` should work as doc_id being null on table 2 will not be there anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a *not exists* scenario.

You can't expect to return data from `c` since by definition what you want doesn't exist:

```
select d.DOCID
from dbo.Custom_SUAM_Docuware d 
where not exists(
  select * from dbo.Custom_SUAM_Content c 
  where c.DOC_ID = d.DOCID
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [EXCEPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
SELECT c.[DOC_ID]
FROM [dbo].[Custom_SUAM_Content] c 
EXCEPT  
SELECT d.[DOC_ID]   
FROM [dbo].[Custom_SUAM_Docuware] d ;
```

that would show all ids from c that are not in d